# Boolean Expression Problem

Tags: boolean-algebra

> $$AB'C'D+ABCD$$
>   $$=AD(B'C'+BC)$$
>   $$=AD$$

I have simplified this expression right but for some reason I still get the answer wrong. The expression $AD$ does not match the original truth table. Please help.

Comment: The thing is though $B'+B=1$ and $C'+C=1$, but $B'C'+BC\ne 1$ for $B=0,C=1$ and $B=1,C=0$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $B'C' \ne (BC)'$

$$AB'C'D + ABCD = AD(B'C' + BC) = AD((B+C)'+BC)$$